# Convert DataFrame column to json column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where one of the column is of json type but it is like below:
column
{1:1,2:2,3:3}

But i would want this to be in real json format like
column
{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3}

Currently the data type of the column is object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import ast
import json
import pandas


def convert_json(row: pandas.Series) -> pandas.Series:

    # Read the string as a python dictionary (literal_eval), then, turn the key into a string, then dump as a valid JSON string
    row["real_json"] = json.dumps({str(key): value for key, value in ast.literal_eval(row["my_json"]).items()})

    # Return the row
    return row


# Some test data
df = pandas.DataFrame([{"my_json": "{1:1,2:2,3:3}"} for _ in range(10)])

# Loop the rows and apply the function
df = df.apply(convert_json, axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
print(df)
         my_json                 real_json
0  {1:1,2:2,3:3}  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
1  {1:1,2:2,3:3}  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
2  {1:1,2:2,3:3}  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
3  {1:1,2:2,3:3}  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
4  {1:1,2:2,3:3}  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
5  {1:1,2:2,3:3}  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
6  {1:1,2:2,3:3}  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
7  {1:1,2:2,3:3}  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
8  {1:1,2:2,3:3}  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
9  {1:1,2:2,3:3}  {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. When i try to open the dataframe in notepad, getting many quotes like "{""1"": 4, ""2"": 3, ""3"": 4}". Can we be able to handle this issue?

Comment: How did you save the dataframe?

Comment: @viswanaththatha, Then that is expected behaviour ;). In CSV quotes have a special meaning. They indicate the start (or end) of a cell. If you use `to_csv` it will try to escape the quotes in the cells of the column `real_json`, adding extra quotes in the process. Add these lines: `import csv` `df.to_csv("test.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar="'")`